# Music/Audio app - seamless from one device to the next

Tags: music

Here's the scenario.

I'm on my Windows computer at home, listening to a podcast or music playlist. I need to go out. I pause the podcast and then, when I'm walking down the street I hit play on my Android phone and continue listening where I left off. A couple of hours later, I'm at work at my desk and want to continue listening (on my work Windows computer) from where I was a couple of hours ago on my walk. Then, later, when I get home again, I want to open my Windows computer and hit play, picking up from where I was listening in the office.

I don't mind where the centrally-stored music or audio is located but I must be able to add to it manually from my collection or from a new download. I **don't** want to have a copy of every music or audio file on each of my devices—I'm after one, central location that all my devices can access. And most important of all, the app must know where I was up to on whichever device I was listening with last. I want to open the app on any device and it knows where I'm up to, so that I can just hit play and resume listening.

This isn't just about audiobooks or podcasts. It could be anything I'm listening to.

Does such an app or setup exist?

Many thanks.

Comment: I just found this: Seamless (http://fivedetails.com/seamless/). It does what I'm after but it's for iPhones and Macs. I'm looking for a Windows and Android solution. Still hoping you've found something to recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to **Z Z** for the suggestion. I definitely *don't* want to host myself. Too much work and too individualised. I'm wanting to hook into something that's being developed and managed online or via an Android/Windows/Web app.

And **I can happily report that I've found something** that does what I need. It's similar in idea to MixCloud but far, FAR more stable on a mobile phone.

[iBroadcast](https://ibroadcast.com/)

It's web-based on my computer and I also have the Android app. To play where I left off I just "join" the device that has what I was listening to. I'm very impressed so far.

Currently free but might cost something soon. It does the trick for now.

Very happy :D

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. But it's not easy or one app. But rather a server and multiple clients.

### MPD (Music Player Deamon)

You would have to get a [MPD](https://www.musicpd.org/) server running which you can then access from anywhere.

A setup could be as simple as a [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) at home running Ubuntu server and MPD with a free domain from a service like [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/) (if you have IPv4 you would have to open at least one port for that). Then you need a MPD client on your Devices to listen. For linux I reccomend [cantata](https://github.com/cdrummond/cantata). For any other systems I don't have any experience but there is a [list of clients](https://www.musicpd.org/clients/). The Files would all sit on the server and the clients would stream everything and possibly cache recent songs/files.

Getting the seamless experience requires proper configuration. You would need to set up playlists or a queue and some plugins. That would take care of the current song. Getting it to restart at the time you last stopped is possible but I have no experience there. You can take a look at the [Documentation](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/html/user.html#configuration) yourself. More specifically the [State-file](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/html/user.html#the-state-file):

> The state file is a file where MPD saves and restores its state (play
> queue, playback position etc.) to keep it persistent across restarts
> and reboots. It is an optional setting.

Comment: Thank you, @totalynotanoob. Not an ideal solution but I could try it out if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to host yourself, you can upload the files to say a service like [MixCloud](https://www.mixcloud.com/), after creating an account. You can then play directly via web browser on any platform (laptop/computer or mobile phone) or via their mobile phone app on Android/iphone. It allows you to create playlists of  material available or uploaded to the site. If you are logged in, it remembers position of last-played on any playlist. So will satisfy your main requirement.

Note: If you decide to host in future, then use [Music Player Daemon (MPD)](https://www.musicpd.org/), and play with any of the [MPD Clients](https://www.musicpd.org/clients/), as also suggested in a previous answer.